# Switch navlistPanel when submitButton pressed

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to change the current tabPanel when the submit button is pressed?

For example, I want to, in one panel, input the data (parameters, files, etc.) and then, after clicking the submit button, change to to de panel where the graphs are created without having to manually changing the panel.

Thanks!